# jdbcTemplate to print foreign key value by postman

Tags: java, groovy, spring-boot

I have below entity class

```
class Task {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
Long id;

Integer plannedEffort;
Integer actualEffort;
Integer workCompletedPercent;

//foreign key field
@ManyToOne
Resource createdBy;

@ManyToOne
Project project;

@ManyToOne
Resource assignedTo;

@ManyToOne
Task parentTaskCode
}
```

And this is service method

```
public List<TaskDTO> getAllResourcesTaskReport(){
log.info(" Service getAllResourcesTaskReport");
String sql="select id,sum(actual_effort) as actual_effort,um(planned_effort) as planned_effort,(actual_effort/planned_effort*100) as work_completed_percent,assigned_to_id,created_by_id,parent_task_code_id,project_id from task group by assigned_to_id";

List<TaskDTO> list  = getJdbcTemplate().query(sql,new BeanPropertyRowMapper(TaskDTO.class));
return list;

}
```

And when I am running code getting this result.

```
  [
  {
    "id": 1181,
    "plannedEffort": 240,
    "actualEffort": 177,
    "workCompletedPercent": 83,
    "createdBy": null,
    "project": null,
    "assignedTo": null,
    "parentTaskCode": null,
    "activity": null
  }
]
```

Please tell me any solution why am I getting null value to foreign key field?